# printf with reserved width of static Strings

Tags: java

I find it kind of weird to use placeholders for static Strings just to achieve the width-reservation/alignment in a `System.out.printf`-statement.

```
System.out.printf("%-10s%s", "Title:", book.getTitle());
```

Is there any way of achieving this exact behaviour while including `"Title:"` in the format-String rather than passing it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the strings and use only one token:

```
System.out.printf("%s", "Title:    " + book.getTitle());
```

I added 6 to your formatted string length, since I assume you want to accommodate for `"Title:"`.

Comment: Wouldn't this produce a different result than the example I posted? I want to reserve a width of 10 for Title:, leaving 4 whitespaces before the title kicks in. Wouldn't your example remove the whitespace preceding the object-title?

Comment: See edit. Apologies, I overlooked that you wanted to ensure space between "Title:" and the book title. If the "Title" string will not change, then you can hardcode the four spaces into it. Otherwise, your approach is just as easy and feasible, if not more so than my solution.

Comment: Yeah, It's not exactly bloated to write `%-10s%s`, I just wish there was a way I could write `-10{Title:}%s` or something like that

Comment: IMO, go with your original solution. If you ever change your string later down the road, you will keep the formatting you want.